# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "--": syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, pycharm, python-3.8

Can't find where is this typo or something - everytime getting this error `line 33, in <module>
    c_a.execute('ATTACH DATABASE temp.db AS check')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "check": syntax error`

I'm trying to attach database `temp.db` to the `prime.db` due one query. This has help me to find duplicate records (checking `login` (one of the columns in both databases))

```
import sqlite3

db_a = sqlite3.connect('prime.db')
c_a = db_a.cursor()

db_b = sqlite3.connect('temp.db')
c_b = db_b.cursor()

c_a.execute('ATTACH DATABASE temp.db AS check')
c_a.execute('SELECT * FROM check.user_info WHERE user_info.login = user.login')
db_a.commit()
c_a.fetchall()
```

Also tried another version:

```
attachDatabaseSQL = "ATTACH DATABASE temp.db AS check"
dbSpec = ("temp.db",)
c_a.execute(attachDatabaseSQL, dbSpec)
c_a.execute('SELECT * FROM check.user_info WHERE user_info.login = user.login')
db_a.commit()
c_a.fetchall()
```

It found the error:
    `line 41, in <module>
    c_a.execute(attachDatabaseSQL, dbSpec)
    sqlite3.OperationalError: near "check": syntax error`

Use Python 3.8.1 and SQLite3.

UPDATE:
Changed it to:

```
c_a.execute('ATTACH DATABASE temp.db AS dbcheck')
c_a.execute('SELECT * FROM check.user_info WHERE user_info.login = user.login')
db_a.commit()
c_a.fetchall()
```

And the ERROR NOW IS:

```
c_a.execute('ATTACH DATABASE temp.db AS dbcheck')
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: temp.db
```

Answer (score 0):

> `ATTACH DATABASE temp.db AS check;`

`check` is a [reserved word in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), as in most (if not all) other databases. In the syntax, it comes into play to define [check constraints when creating tables](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

Consider using another name, that does not conflict with a language keyword. For example:

```
ATTACH DATABASE temp.db AS dbcheck;
```

Comment: Well, tried this but, appears another error this time... `c_a.execute('ATTACH DATABASE crm.db AS dbcheck') c_a.execute('SELECT * FROM check.user_info WHERE user_info.login = user.login') db_a.commit() c_a.fetchall() print('Records have been deduplicated.')` error this time is: `line 33, in <module> c_a.execute('ATTACH DATABASE temp.db AS dbcheck') sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: temp.db`